# Cloud functions: Error: No document to update

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My database is set up so whenever a user makes a post, their name and image info save together with the post to save on reads (by not calling for a read to the user's data for every post that's being read).

I am trying to build a function that changes the name of a user in all the post instances where they were the author, when that user changes their name in the settings.

*note: all posts in my app are questions.

I have deployed it and tried to test it, by changing the name of a user I am certain has a question that where they are the author of (I can see that in the data). Also the path is also right as long as I am using the wildcards properly, which as far as I understand I am.

When I do that, their name doesn't change in the question data set.

When I look at the logs I see this error:

```
Error: No document to update: projects/my-projects-name/databases/(default)/documents/communities_data/4ORj0bh9rpi2Ns5vj4pW/questions/undefined
    at Http2CallStream.call.on (/srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:96:45)
    at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
    at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at process.nextTick (/srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:71:22)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

I don't understand why the would be as I know for certain there is a document that corresponds to that query.

This is my function:

```
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore.document('communities_data/{community}/profiles/{profileID}').onUpdate((change, context) => {
    // Retrieve the current and previous value
    const data = change.after.data();
    const previousData = change.before.data();

    // We'll only update if the name has changed.
    // This is crucial to prevent infinite loops.
    if (data !== undefined && previousData !== undefined) {

        if (data.name !== previousData.name || data.image !== previousData.image) {

            return db.collection('communities_data/' + context.params.community + '/questions').where('author_ID', '==', context.params.profileID).get()
                .then(snapshot => {

                    if(snapshot.size >0){
                        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                            const question = doc.data as unknown as Question
                            const promises = []
                            const p = db.doc('communities_data/' + context.params.community + '/questions/' + question.id)
                                .update({
                                    author_name: data.name,
                                    author_image: data.image
                                });
                            promises.push(p)
                            return Promise.all(promises)
                        })
                    }
                }
                )

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
});
```

This is my Question class:

```
class Question {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    details: string;
    language: Number;
    tags: Array<string>;
    timestamp: Number;
    author_ID: string;
    author_name: string;
    author_image: string;
    answers: Number;
    last_interaction: Number;
    score_items: Number;
    constructor(id: string, title: string, details: string, language: Number, tags: [], timestamp: Number, author_ID: string, author_name: string, author_image: string, answers: Number, last_interaction: Number, score_items: Number) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.details = details;
        this.language = language;
        this.tags = tags;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.author_ID = author_ID;
        this.author_name = author_name;
        this.author_image = author_image;
        this.answers = answers;
        this.last_interaction = last_interaction;
        this.score_items = score_items;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `doc.data as unknown as Question`?

Comment: should it be `doc.data()`

Comment: I tried to convert the document to an object of type question so I can access its variables. I haven't tried it with parenthesis, I'll give it a go and update

Comment: @NaeemShaikh that was correct and solved my problem, if you'll add it as an answer I'll accept it